# What systems files should I back up when upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, backup

I wonder which systems files I should back up before upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS? I am specifically interested in files **outside** of $HOME, as I have $HOME backed up anyway.

I've seen some recommendations including the following dirs/files:

```
/etc
/var/lib/apt/extended_states
/var/lib/dpkg
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

as well as the output of

```
dpkg --get-selections "*"
```

Any other recommendations? Or places where this might be documented?

Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to backup any system file you plan to reuse, anything you've edited or created. Other than that, 22.04 has its own system files. There aren't any recommended or not recommended files to backup.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'm wondering what files I might want to reuse - e.g., reinstall previously installed applications / packages / snaps. There are some files (e.g., for xkb) that I've edited - so yes, those need backing up as well.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the only items that need to be backed up are your personal data. These are unique and irreplaceable. User configuration data, and especially system configuration data, can always be restored or repaired.

So as soon as the backup of your personal files is in order, sleep on both ears. Even if your system totally breaks, nothing of serious concern can happen.

Out of convenience, you can make a backup of your configuration data under your home directory. One caveat: if you restore these configuration under a newer version of the operating system, there is a slight chance that something breaks. The format of configuration files may have changed between versions, and no-one guarantees that your old configuration data will work with a newer version.

Backing up system configuration data for a personal computer makes little sense unless you have time to spare. A Linux distribution overall comes with sane defaults, and it is easy enough to change these little things you may want differently after install.